# Failed to create collection "shard1_replica" not create any idea how can i config and fix this problem?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

```
"responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":634},
  "failure":{
    "localhost:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at null: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'servicedesk_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [servicedesk_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_en.txt' in classpath or '/configs/servicedesk', cwd=/opt/solr-9.0.0/server"},
  "Operation create caused exception:":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: servicedesk",
  "exception":{
    "msg":"Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: servicedesk",
    "rspCode":400},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your fields in schema is expecting `lang/stopwords_en.txt` file to be present. You need to add this file in your configset's directory.
For eg. if your configset dir name `servicedesk`. Your stopword file will be at the path  servicedesk/lang/stopwords_en.txt